# Client firewall blocks all ports but 80 and 443, need away to forward requets on port 443 to SSH or HTTPS

Tags: https, ssh, firewall, port, forwarding

I am currently working at a client were they have locked down the network, except for ports 80 and 443. I need to connect to our server using SSH, but the same server also runs our website. We do not want to invest in a new server or place a second network card.

I have been searching the internet for away to setup our linux server (running CentOS 5), so that there is a daemon listening on port 443 that depending on the client protocol forwards the request to the correct internal port (SSH 22 or HTTPS moved to a differentport_.

There are a lot of people on internet looking for this kind solution, but no clear instructions how to do this.

Anyone have ideas/clear instructions how to do this?

Regards, nidkil

Comment: Most of the times port 443 is also open out. If your webserver doesn't support HTTPS you can forward that port to 22 in your firewall.

Comment: true, but he wants to run HTTPS!

Answer (score 6):

sslh : http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml

I'm using 1.5; I haven't tried 1.6b yet, and 1.3 has a problem with leaving zombies around.

Run it on port 443; if no data is sent with 2 seconds (the default), it forwards to ssh. Otherwise, it forwards to your web server.

I'm running it on my website (http://mikeage.net) -- you can netcat in if you want to see both login banners.

In my case, it also has another purpose. We have an even more restrictive setup than you: all ports are blocked, but 80 and 443 can be reached via proxy. I can have SSH use a program like corkscrew (or putty natively) to proxy my SSH connection via the company proxy to my server:443, where after a brief delay, my SSH server responds with it's login banner. I can also serve webpages over the standard HTTPS (and do, in fact).

Comment: Nice. +1. See comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487737. 1 down, 14 to go (1 per day)

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution to your problem might be to assign multiple IP addresses to your box and bind your SSH to port 443 on a separate IP; [you can usually assign multiple IP addresses to a single adapter](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/redhat/bind_multiple_ip_addresses_to_single_nic/index.php), no need to add a second network card. Otherwise I don't know of any out of the box solutions for what you want to do. You would probably have to create a custom daemon for that, which would be a little tricky but doable.

Comment: This is probably the best solution if he has multiple IPs available.

Answer (score 3):

The firewall restrictions are in place for a reason.   They may not be good ones, but they make sense to the person who implemented it or caused it to be implemented.  I wouldn't attempt to violate the company policy on external connections.

If your need is legitimate, I would request that the port, or an alternate, be opened to the addresses you require.  If that doesn't work then perhaps a VPN solution would be acceptable.

In the case where the network folks are just insanely protective, unwilling to respond to reason, or plain incompetent, I'd want to make sure I had sign-off from a manager who's willing to go to bat for me WHEN it becomes an issue before I implemented a work-around.  Anything else could reasonably end up with your employment being terminated.  After all, you are talking about violating a company security policy.

Comment: Pretend he's in Thailand or some other country that blocks SSH. Of course you'd be risking the secret police instead of just your emploer's wrath. Probably need to stealth SSH inside gif's too then ;)

Comment: Good point about using SSH to bypass security. Most security people don't like it when you circumvent their rules, and they usually have a lot of pull.

As far as having someone open the port, I guess you've never worked in a big company before where policy trumps any good reason one might have?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a small web application listening on port 443 that enables a reverse SSH shell towards the IP of the incoming connection, using public key authentication.
Say:

- You authenticate on the web application; the web application retrieves your IP
- The application starts a SSH tunnel from its IP to your IP (at port 22)
- The SSH server on your machine ends the tunnel and listens at localhost:8080
- Then, you start a SSH session with localhost:8080. The commands in the following interactive session are redirected to the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

If you have apache on our centos box, you can use mod_proxy to redirect requests from one port to another. I use this to redirect requests to http://webmin.myserver.com to http://myserver.com:10000 (webmin running on an inaccessible port)

```
ServerName webmin.myserver.co.uk
SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / https://myserver.co.uk:10000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://myserver.co.uk:10000/
```

Place the above in your virtual server directive, and you're good to go. This may not work with Putty, but if you install webmin it has a SSH module you can access via a browser.