# How can I ssh into my EC2 instance from my local computer which has only ports 80 and 443 allowed?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, firewall

I have recently starred out with EC2. Currently I am using the Free Tier to test and learn about it. However as I am behind a proxy that allows only connections at port 80 and 443, I am unable to connect the  EC2 instance. Is there a way to get past this ?

So far I've guess that running sslh on the EC2 instance, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410995/client-firewall-blocks-all-ports-but-80-and-443-need-away-to-forward-requets-on) might help. But I am not sure if this behavior should remain persistent once the instance is terminated and re-started (as I am using Free Tier). Is there a way I can achieve persistence in terms of settings and installed resources like sslh (and many others) while using the Free Tier ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once when behind a firewall that only allowed outgoing communication on ports such as 80, I just ran an sshd on the server on a different port.  You won't be able to set this up while behind the firewall, you'll have to go somewhere else, ssh in, and reconfigure ssh.

Instead of running sshd on a non-standard port, you could also just have something redirect traffic from some other port to port 22.

If your ec2 instance isn't running a web server, you can use port 80 or 443 for the sshd.  If you're not using https, then use 443.

You say they only allow outgoing traffic to remote ports 80 and 443, but often times ports above 1024 are also unblocked.

Make sure you've also correctly configured your security groups on the ec2 instance, since it has a firewall as well.  You'll have to make sure it's configured to allow incoming traffic on the port supplying the sshd from your IP address.  This can be done through the aws management console.

Comment: You can set up sshd on port 80 or port 443 when you first run the EC2 instance by passing in the setup commands in the user-data script. Here's an old article I wrote on how to do this: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-ssh-port-80

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-ssh-port-80) there's is a neat solution. I haven't tried it. The idea is to pass a script to boot the instance with ssh bind to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Goto instances 
at the top of the list of your running instances you should see "instance action"
In that menu you should see "connect"
Select "connect from your browser using Java ssh client"

note, you need Java to be installed.

Comment: you do understand that SSH is like a FTP access to all the files... not having a console mode, right?